# Pressing two buttons at the same time, wp7, silverlight, c#

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, multi-touch

I'm still working with sound effects on my test app and I noticed that you can't press on two buttons at the same time. Is there a way to allow this? So that I can press the two buttons at the same time with two fingers. I was looking at multi touch support from GalaSoft and hit testing but it doesn't seem like these are the right solutions.

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at the Gesture stuff in the Silverlight Toolkit? (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't press multiple buttons at the same time but you could create your own control which detects simultaneous presses in different areas of the control and mimics separate button presses.